# Media Queries not working in Chrome, works in Firefox

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a whole range of stylesheets that are specific to many different resolutions. 
I link to them using references in the header, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="http://site.com/child-theme/1024.css" />
```

In Firefox they work without a hitch, but in Chrome (and possibly Safari) it doesn't honor the media queries, even though it clearly detects/sees them as they are viewable in Firebug, however they are crossed out.

Can't for the life of me figure it out... any help solving this puzzle would be much appreciated!

My (wordpress) site is: [HBB-Inc.com](http://www.hbb-inc.com)
To view how it should look, check it out in Firefox... and then compare in Chrome.

Comment: have you tried using double quotes ( " ) on all attributes, instead of mixing single ( ' ) and double ones?

Comment: Tried using all double quotes but problem still remains. According to Firebug the browser (Chrome) clearly detects the media query stylesheets that are supposed to be applied, but the CSS itself gets crossed out in favor of the main stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the nature of **CSS**, it stands for **C***ascading* **S***tyle* **S***heets*.

An amended quote on this from a number of places on the internet:

> Cascade is the special part. A style sheet is intended to cascade
>   through a series of style rules, like a river over a waterfall. The
>   water in the river hits all the rocks in the waterfall, but only the
>   ones at the bottom affect exactly where the water will flow. The same
>   is true of the cascade in style sheets.

In other words, because your `media="all"` style sheets are linked lower down in your head section they are affecting the look of the very same elements which you have styled earlier in the process.

I think moving the style sheets with their `media` attribute set to `all` to the start of your head section will fix your problem

Comment: Okay that seems to have gotten me somewhere... however problem still remains. After moving the style sheets with media attribute set to all above the rest, Chrome has placed the correct (relevant) stylesheet above the other (and un-crossed), however even though the main stylesheet rules are crossed out, it's still in effect using their rules.

Comment: I'm not that well versed in media queries, but yours look a bit odd to me, does it not make sense that if you specify a stylesheet with the media query `(min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1024px)` that that stylesheet will only be applied if the width is exactly 1024px? so in your case, wouldn't the media queries only work at exactly 1024px, 1152px, 1280px and so on, and at any width in between they would just fall back on your `media="all"` style sheets?

Comment: yeah that was my objective seeing as with the theme/layout I am using, it needs to be adjusted on just about all different widths for it to look the same.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't you then still specify: `from 1024px up to 1152px, look like this` and `from 1152px up to 1280px, look like this`? For example, my screen is `1920px` wide, but yourr `media="all"` styles lay things out in such a way that I have a scroll bar on the right, now the effective width is only `1903px`, so your style sheet doesn't get applied, if I re-size my browser window so that the document excluding the scroll bar is exactly `1024px`, then your style sheet for `1024px` starts working. Things would have looked fine here if you had specified `from 1680px to 1920px look like this..`